# How do I automatically have multiple cursors in a Sublime Text 3 snippet?

Tags: sublimetext3, code-snippets, cursors

I have a console log snippet for Sublime Text 3.

```
{
    "keys": ["alt+super+l"],
    "command": "insert_snippet", 
    "args": {
        "contents": "console.log('$1', $2)"
    },
    "context": [
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
    ]
}
```

I would like for there to be multiple cursors, so that, when I call the key for this snippet, the cursor is at both the $1 and the $2 locations, as I often just want to log the variable name and the variable value in the console. How do I manage this?

Comment: use the same variable `$1` for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`${1:placeholder}`](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html#placeholders) (or just [`$1`](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html#mirrored-fields)) in both places. For your particular snippet, it will look something like:

```
{ ...
        "contents": "console.log('${1:variable}', ${1:variable})"
    ...
}
```

If you don't want a placeholder and just want the cursor in two places, it'll look like this:

```
{ ...
        "contents": "console.log('$1', $1)"
    ...
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.